# Problem : Candlestick chart covering complete y-axis in the form of bars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, candlestick-chart

I am making a candlesticks chart using Plotly python. But my candlesticks cover the whole y-axis and are in the form of bars. Instead, I want them to look like a normal candlestick chart.
The code is  presented below:[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
df = pd.read_csv(r"MMM_15m_traditional.csv")
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Time'],
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['Close'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['High'])])
fig.update_layout(
    title='MMM_15m_traditional',
    yaxis_title='MMM Data',
)

fig.show()
```

The output is as under:
[image]

But using the sample data from the plotly website into the same code, I get the normal candlesticks.

The code using the plotly website's data is as under :

[image]

The output:

[image]

The output of the "df.head" is shwon  below :
[image]

Comment: 'Unnamed 0' may be affected. Try the following. `df=pd.read_csv(r"MMM_15m_traditional.csv", index_col=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this below code, which is reproducable in any system and check if you are still facing issue. Install investpy library.

Pls share dataframe `df.head()` output to check the values in your csv files, may be the data is not correct so you are facing issue.

Always share reproducible code so that other can copy and test in their system.I don't know your `df` and cannot reproduce from image you uploaded.

try removing `hover_text = df['Symbol]` from the code.

Reproducible Code-

```
pip install investpy
import pandas as pd
import investpy
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px
df = investpy.get_index_historical_data(index="Nifty 50",country="India",from_date=("23/03/2022"),to_date= "23/04/2022")
df.tail(10)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                open=df['Open'], high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'], name = 'Nifty50')])
fig.show()
```

The Viz is created succesfully-

[image: Viz]

Your Code with exact `df`.Also remove column `Unnamed 0` from csv or `df`

```
df.head()
Date    Time    Open    Close   High    Low
0   2021-04-12  09:31:00    198.25  198.76  197.54  197.54
1   2021-04-12  09:45:00    198.79  199.10  199.27  198.67
2   2021-04-12  10:00:AM    199.13  198.41  199.29  198.35
3   2021-04-12  10:15:AM    198.46  198.35  198.68  198.27
```

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('hii.xlsx')
df

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Time'],
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['Close'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['High'])])
fig.update_layout(
    title='MMM_15m_traditional',
    yaxis_title='MMM Data',
)
```

Viz-
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have updated my question so kindly check it again. Secondly, removing the "hover_text = df['Symbol]" has not made any different output.

Comment: updated the code based on your `df`